# Setting value for config of Spring @Scheduled from database

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-scheduled

Some method has been Annotated with `@Scheduled(fixedDelay=/.../)`, how can I get that value from the database?
already have needed service and repository, just not sure how to apply that value here.

Comment: Could be , will try this approach, thanks !

Answer (score 6):

You can define a bean in a @Configuration class somewhere else in your project which reads the delay rate from the database:

```
@Bean
public Long myFixedDelay() {
   return myRepository.myDatabaseCallToGetDelay();
}
```

You can then reference this bean in your @Scheduled annotation using Spring EL:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{@myFixedDelay}")
```

Comment: hmm, strange. I cannot call it that way, it requires for value to be (long)

Comment: Oh I realised I made I mistake. To do it this way you need to use fixedDelayString instead of fixedDelay. Ill update my answer